# React Native await promise never executes

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, bluetooth, async-await

I am trying to build a react-native bluetooth app, but this is my first time working with react-native. 
I have an asycn function that I am calling witch is calling `await BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices()` but nothing happens it just waits.
What am I missing?

Full function code

```
async discoverUnpaired () {
      if (this.state.discovering) {
        console.log("true: ", this.state.discovering)
        this.setState({ discovering: false })
        return false
      } else {
        this.setState({ discovering: true })
        try{
          console.log("false: ", this.state.discovering)
          await BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices()
          .then((unpairedDevices) => {
            this.setState({ unpairedDevices, discovering: false })
            console.log("false: ", this.state.discovering)
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
          }
        catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        } 
      }
    }
```

P.S. Sorry for the bad code, just researching react-native bluetooth for a project.
If anyone has a good tutorial for react-native classic bluetooth that would also help a lot.

**EDIT**

After changing the code to

```
const unpairedDevices = await BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices();
this.setState({ unpairedDevices, discovering: false });
console.log("devices: ", unpairedDevices);
```

the problem is still there. 
I think that this is just a bug in the library because if call `BluetoothSerial.list()` instead of `BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices()` it workes

Comment: You're mixing `await` with `.then` promise syntax. That kinda defeats the point of using `async/await`.

Comment: try to return after await

Comment: the problem described would imply that `BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices()` never resolves - perhaps [this issue](https://github.com/nuttawutmalee/react-native-bluetooth-serial-next/issues/7) and a solution presented within explains the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the suggestion but requesting permissions for coarse location didn't help me. Still the same. The code after await is not executed but if another button calls another function it works.

Answer (score 0):

To properly utilise async/await syntax, your code should look more like this:

```
   try{
      console.log("false: ", this.state.discovering)
      const unpairedDevices = await BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices();
      this.setState({ unpairedDevices, discovering: false });
      console.log("false: ", this.state.discovering);
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
```

Comment: while this code is *more correct* it doesn't address the issue

Comment: `const unpairedDevices = await BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices();
console.log("false: ", this.state.discovering);
console.log("devices: ", unpairedDevices);`
even when I do it like this no code is executed after await. But other functions called are working.

Comment: @MilanNikolić did you have a question about that bit of code?

Comment: @TKoL even after changing to your code the await function doesn't execute

Comment: Ah right, might be a problem with setting up your app then. I only have a vague familiarity with building android apps, you might need to configure permissions to use bluetooth or something

Answer (score 0):

After trying the changes written in the edit part of the question I tried using `BluetoothSerial.list()` and it worked but only showed already pared devices while `BluetoothSerial.listUnpaired()` and `BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices()` didn't work. 
This was all done on my **Xiaomi Mi Mix 2S** phone. After using a Nokia phone from my friend everything worked as expected, both `BluetoothSerial.listUnpaired()` and `BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpairedDevices()`.